How can you check if a javascript map has a duplicate key
I'm working with a Map in JavaScript and need to check that it doesn't contain duplicate keys. The map I'm working with is below.
const colors = new Map([
    [1, 'blue'],
    [2, 'orange'],
    [1, 'pink'], // This duplicate key should trigger an error
    [3, 'yellow'],
]);

In this situation because the number 1 is used two times as a key that should throw an error.
I cannot modify the colors variable directly. Instead, I need to make a function that checks for duplicate keys in the Map and throw an error if a duplicate is found.
This is what I currently have. The problem is that when you use a duplicate key in the map it overrides the previous key and value so it's as if a duplicate key is never in the map.


const colors = new Map([
    [1, 'blue'],
    [2, 'orange'],
    [1, 'pink'], // This duplicate key should trigger an error
    [3, 'yellow'],
]);

const iterator = colors.keys();

console.log(iterator.next().value);
// output: 1

console.log(iterator.next().value);
// output: 2

console.log(iterator.next().value);
// output: 3




You have to check the nested array, before you call new Map. The map doesn't have duplicate keys. The entry is overwritten and the information is gone.

"I cannot modify the colors variable directly." Reason?

As jabaa explains, what you're asking (basically, to go back in time) is impossible.

As @jabaa said if you console.log colors you will see that you have overwritten your key, value pair when key = 1, now you have pink not blue. So you can use a function before adding any pair value to check if the same initial values are still present or that the length of colors has not changed (when you overwright)

"Cannot modify the colors variable directly" is an odd restriction. Please explain.

You cannot have the same two keys in map. Once you have tried to write a value with the same key, it will override previous value. What I mean:

If you want to check if a Map contains some key before writing it to it, you can just use Map.has method:
if (map.has(key)) throw new Error(`Map is already contains key: "${key}"`)


I have addd checkForDuplicateKeys
the Set (seenKeys) keep track of keys.
if a duplicate key is found it throws an error.


function checkForDuplicateKeys(entries) {
    const seenKeys = new Set(); 
    
    for (const [key, value] of entries) {
        if (seenKeys.has(key)) {
            throw new Error(`duplicate key found: ${key}`);
        }
        seenKeys.add(key); // add the key to the set
    }
}

const colorEntries = [
    [1, 'blue'],
    [2, 'orange'],
    [1, 'pink'], // This duplicate key should trigger an error
    [3, 'yellow'],
];

try {
    checkForDuplicateKeys(colorEntries); 
    //if no error
    const colors = new Map(colorEntries); 
    console.log(colors);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message); 
}




The question contains "I cannot modify the colors variable directly."
